# Apache Tomcat using old resources - changes in Eclipse project not reflected in Web App

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets, eclipse-classpath

I am using the Eclipse Java EE IDE with Apache Tomcat version 6 to develop a web application.

The structure of the application is very simple, there are just two classes, one is the servlet class and the other is a object which is built by the servlet and does most of the work.

The problem that I am having is this: since this morning changes which I have made to both class files have not been appeared in the behaviour of the Web application. The application essentially behaves as if it is running my code from yesterday. To make sure that this is the case, I temporarily altered the behaviour of the program in radical ways and low, these changes still did not affect the web application.

Some relevant information:I am running Ubuntu 12, my Eclipse project is set to build automatically, and the tomcat server is configured to auto load modules by default and to automatically publish whenever a resource is changed. I have also cleaned 
out the server's working directory.

How can I overcome this issue? I need my web application to implement the changes which I have made to the source code of my servlet and the class which the servlet uses.

Comment: Try restarting the server. You can also try adding and removing the project from the server.

Comment: I tried both of these, I restarted the server, removed the project and added them back in, purposefully republished the server, all of this after refreshing my eclipse project as well.

Comment: I have even deleted the old project, built a new dynamic web project, and imported my two source code files and the dependencies all back into the new project folder, yet Tomcat still hasn't implemented changes that I have made 0_0

Comment: is your tomcat server.xml pointing to the right Workspace? server.xml can be find in your tomcat installation directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the Tomcat server in the standar way in the tabs *Servers*, the *deploy path* lives in the `.metadata` directory of your workspace.

The next tree directory is for my workspace. I added Tomcat 7.

```
MY_WORKSPACE
+---.metadata
|   \---.plugins
|       +---org.eclipse.wst.server.core
|       |   |   monitors.xml
|       |   |   publish.xml
|       |   |   servers.xml
|       |   |   tmp-data.xml
|       |   |   
|       |   +---publish
|       |   |       publish0.dat
|       |   |       publish1.dat
|       |   |       
|       |   \---tmp0
|       |       +---conf
|       |       |   |   catalina.policy
|       |       |   |   catalina.properties
|       |       |   |   context.xml
|       |       |   |   server.xml
|       |       |   |   tomcat-users.xml
|       |       |   |   web.xml
|       |       |   |   
|       |       |   \---Catalina
|       |       |       \---localhost
|       |       +---logs
|       |       |       catalina.2013-07-06.log
|       |       |       catalina.2013-07-11.log
|       |       |       host-manager.2013-07-06.log
|       |       |       host-manager.2013-07-11.log
|       |       |       localhost.2013-07-06.log
|       |       |       localhost.2013-07-11.log
|       |       |       localhost_access_log.2013-07-06.txt
|       |       |       localhost_access_log.2013-07-11.txt
|       |       |       manager.2013-07-06.log
|       |       |       manager.2013-07-11.log
|       |       |       
|       |       +---temp
|       |       +---webapps
|       |       +---work
|       |       |   \---Catalina
|       |       |       \---localhost
|       |       \---wtpwebapps
|       |           +---ROOT
|       |           |   \---WEB-INF
|       |           |           web.xml
|       |           |           
|       |           \---MyWebProject
|       |               |   index.html
|       |               |       
|       |               \---WEB-INF
|       |                   +---classes
|       |                   |   |   
|       |                   |   \---several-packages-and-clases
|       |                   \---lib
|       |                           log4j-1.2.17.jar
|       |                           slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
|       |                           slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
|       |                           
|       \---org.other.plugins
|               
\---Servers
    |   .project
    |   
    +---.settings
    |       org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
    |       
    \---Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config
            catalina.policy
            catalina.properties
            context.xml
            server.xml
            tomcat-users.xml
            web.xml
```

The *real path* for my web application `MyWebProject` is in the directory `wtpwebapps`. You can delete `MyWebProject` and try again.

If you have several Tomcat's in your workspace, you see directories like `tmp0`, `tmp1`, `tmp2` ...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue , in my case even if the tmp0 folder was correctly updated with new class files and resource files, still I was getting the same issue.
In my case, i got it resolved by disabling jrebel plugin for eclipse. I had jrebel installed in eclipse which was still monitoring and deploying the project from other workspace (not even this workspace), I am going to raise a bug to jrebel team as well.
Simply disable jrebel for that project and get it working back to normal